# Generics + optional parameter in Java can't be combined

Tags: java, generics

I am searching for an elegant solutions for the following problem:

```
//one interface
public interface MyInterface () {
}
//two implementations
public class ImplA implements MyInterface (){ 
}
public class ImplB implements MyInterface () {
}
```

In another class:

```
//one generic method
public void myMethod(Class<MyInterface>... myTypes) {
  for (Class<MyInterface> myType : myTypes) {
     System.err.println("my Type:" +myType);
  }
}
```

The issue is that you cannot simply invoke this method with:

```
myMethod(ImplA.class, ImplB.class);
```

This is just simply not accepted. Is it true that optional parameter and generics can't be combined? I cannot find any example.

Comment: That said, it _is_ true that varargs and generics really don't get along -- indeed, generics and arrays don't really get along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try

```
public void myMethod(Class<? extends MyInterface>... myTypes) {
```

`Class<MyInterface>` has to be `MyInterface.class` not a subclass.

Comment: by using a wildcard I have to suppress warnings when I will invoke the method at: myMethod(ImplA.class, ImplB.class);
  => Type safety : A generic array of Class<? extends MyInterface> is created for a varargs 
  parameter

Comment: Java doesn't like mixing arrays with generics. You can suppress warnings if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `? extends` wildcard to get it to work.

```
public void myMethod(Class<? extends MyInterface>... myTypes) {
    for (Class<? extends MyInterface> myType : myTypes) {
        System.err.println("my Type:" +myType);
    }
}
```

The way you originally did it requires that the *reference* type of each implementer is `MyInterface`.  With my proposed way, you are allowed to have your references be `MyInterface` or any child (grandchildren, etc) of `MyInterface`.

Comment: The `myType` variable in the for loop also needs to be typed as `Class<? extends MyInterface>`

Comment: It is true, it will work, however by using a wildcard I have to suppress warnings when I will invoke the method at: myMethod(ImplA.class, ImplB.class); => Type safety : A generic array of Class<? extends MyInterface> is created for a varargs parameter. Isn't there a way to code that snippet without the need to suppress warnings?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the argument type covariant (define an upper bound). There is only one type which has the signature `Class<X>`, and that is `X.class`. Subtypes are of type `Class<? extends X>`. So:

```
@SafeVarargs 
public void myMethod(Class<? extends MyInterface>... myTypes) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: by using a wildcard I have to suppress warnings when I will invoke the method at: myMethod(ImplA.class, ImplB.class); => Type safety : A generic array of Class<? extends MyInterface> is created for a varargs parameter

Comment: Oh, right - generics and arrays don't play nice together. You can annotate the method with [`@SafeVarargs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html) to get rid of the warnings once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public  void  myMethod(Class<? extends MyInterface>... myTypes) {
      for (Class<?> myType : myTypes) {
         System.err.println("my Type:" +myType);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use bounded wildcard for declaring your generic type - `Class<? extends MyInterface>`

```
public void myMethod(Class<? extends MyInterface>... myTypes) {
  for (Class<? extends MyInterface> myType : myTypes) {
     System.err.println("my Type:" +myType);
  }
}
```